# Opening and closing a process using bash

Tags: bash, firefox, unix, process, kill

Using Ubuntu, I would like to create a shell script (bash) for an Ubuntu server, that will open an instance of firefox and then close **that** specific instance the browser?

To open an instance of firefox, I can write:

```
firefox www.example.com
```

I have read that to search for all firefox instances, and to close them **manually** I can write:

```
ps aux | grep firefox
pidof firefox
kill #process#
```

But is there a way for me to search for the **specific** instance  instance of firefox that I opened at the start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `jobs` to get the IDs of all running processes started from that shell (e.g. inside your script)

```
#!/bin/bash

firefox www.example.com &
PID=$(jobs -p)

kill $PID
```

See `help jobs` for the options. Note that `jobs` lists *all process started from this shell*, so if you follow this approach and want to kill multiple processes you might need to do some additional parsing on the output from `jobs` to find the correct process.

Comment: Also this introduces an awful race condition, if the instance that had been started and which's pid was saved to `PID` had terminate already prior to calling `kill` **and** another process got this very pid assigned in the meanwhile. Then the wrong process would be `kill`ed!

Comment: @leenremm: Take a lot at Brian's answer as well which works better when you start multiple processes. Also, both Brian's and my answer have a race condition as pointed out by alk.

Comment: it doesn't work if you already have a firefox window open. it seems that that newly launched process merges into the existing one, and its original pid disappears from `jobs -p`

Answer (score 1):

Start the process in the background, and remember its pid.

```
#!/bin/bash
firefox www.example.com &
declare -i PID=$!
# blah, blah, blah
kill ${PID}
```

If you're worried about firefox exiting and some other process being assigned ${PID} in the mean time you could change the kill to something like the following to reduce the risk:

```
ps -p ${PID} | fgrep firefox && kill ${PID}
```